# How to wait for response from web service using Typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, https

How to wait for response in this code. 
In this code I post product in ws. My problem is when the response from the ws is being delayed, it may happen that I press the button to submit several times. I have to wait for the response to not be able to press the button many times.

```
  public createproduct(newprod: Product): Observable<boolean> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let body = newprod.generateUrlencodedParameters(this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);
    return this.http.post(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.createproduct), body, {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 0) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      });
  }
```

Can you suggest me any idea how to implement this?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an async call.

So what you do is, you return an Observable object, which will, in the future, change and return something.

What you want to do, is to disable the function after the first call, until it responses with something.

So, if your button is something like `<button (click)=sendRequest() ...` then you should implement it that like this:

```
<button (click)=sendRequest(), [disabled]="areWeWaiting">CLICK ME</button>

areWeWaiting = false;

sendRequest(){
  this.areWeWaiting = true;
  this.someService.createProduct().subscribe(response =>{
   this.areWeWaiting = false;
   // process the call here 
  }, error =>{ this.areWeWaiting = false; //process error here}
  );
}
```

Also, I suggest you remove the `.map` part in the original service call - handle the request where you need to, with the new [httpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) api

Comment: Very helpful for me. Thank you.